# Convertion of Scala typed collection to Java with an unbounded wildcard, etc. Collection<?>

Tags: java, generics, collections, scala

Problem: 
 Need to implement interface from 3rd party Java library in Scala

...

`Collection<?> getItemPropertyIds()`

...

My solution is to use 
`...<here goes  Iterable>.asInstanceOf[java.util.Collection[_]]`

```
 val props:Map[Object,Property] = ...
 override def getItemPropertyIds()=props.keys.asInstanceOf[java.util.Collection[_]]
```

Is there better solution? Maybe with Predef's implicits?

Answer (score 1):

Create some scala.Iterable, use scala.collection.asJavaCollection() (may be implicitly) to convert to java.util.Collection.

Answer (score 1):

I try also this:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions
...
override def getItemPropertyIds() = JavaConversions.asCollection(props.keys)
```

Comment: So, did this solution work the way you want (and are you happy with it), or didn't it?