# convert scala hashmap with List to java hashmap with java list

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am new to scala and spark.I have below case class A

`case class A(uniqueId : String,
               attributes: HashMap[String, List[String]])`

Now I have a dataFrame of type A. I need to call a java function on each row of that DF. I need to convert Hashmap to Java HashMap and List to java list..
How can i do that.

I am trying to do following

```
val rddCaseClass = RDD[A]
val a = rddCaseClass.toDF().map ( x=> {
val rowData = x.getAs[java.util.HashMap[String,java.util.List[String]]]("attributes")
callJavaMethod(rowData)
```

But this is giving me error :

> java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to java.util.List

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convertion of Scala typed collection to Java with an unbounded wildcard, etc. Collection<?>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447946/convertion-of-scala-typed-collection-to-java-with-an-unbounded-wildcard-etc-co)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can convert Scala Wrapped array to Java List using
>   `scala.collection.JavaConversions`

```
 val wrappedArray: WrappedArray[String] = WrappedArray.make(Array("Java", "Scala"))
 val javaList = JavaConversions.mutableSeqAsJavaList(wrappedArray)
```

> `JavaConversions.asJavaList` can also be used but its deprecated: use `mutableSeqAsJavaList` instead

Answer (score 0):

I think, you could use Seq instead of List for your parameters to work efficiently with List. This way it should work with most of the Seq implementations and no need to to convert the seqs like WrappedArray.

```
val rddCaseClass = RDD[A]
val a = rddCaseClass.toDF().map ( x=> {
val rowData = x.getAs[java.util.HashMap[String, Seq[String]]]("attributes")
callJavaMethod(rowData)
```